# Pass object from one dll to another on the runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, .net-2.0

I have 2 projects, in one project I have one form and class with different information, this information is acquiring only during runtime, now in another project I have another form, that will use the object of the first class to get the information and to put it inside form.

Basically I did some research and tried using Reflection for that, but all of the examples I found didn't work properly (actually didn't work at all).

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile("Server.GUI.LocalGUI.dll");
        object o = a.CreateInstance("ServerManager");
        Type t = o.GetType();
```

this is the code that I tried, not sure if it's correct...

I am using .net 2.0

Is anyone have working example of how to use data of one object in another dll on the runtime?

Comment: Why don't you post some code to give us an idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Just reference one project / dll within the other and create a model to pass the data.  I'm not sure you'd need to use reflection in this case.

Comment: your question is not clear to me....can you brief with an example? What kind of object do you want to pass on runtime between projects. Basically objects are accessed by taking project reference. But still not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this all running within the same process?

Comment: What I guess from your word, 2 projects, means you want to pass on some sort of application data to another project's class(es) for processing? If so, you have to modify the constructor of the another project's class(es) to receive data as parameters.

Comment: dude....tell us your requirement please, with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 projects : `MyForm1` and `MyForm2`. Take reference of project `MyForm1` in `MyForm2`. Fill `MyForm1`. Create a instance of the `MyForm1` in `MyForm2` and access the method and its value.

Or create another `Library` project. Expose a static variable in it. Take reference of this library in both the Forms projects. Assign some value from `MyForm1` and access the same property in `MyForm2`.

But if you really want your code to be a managed code, try learning and implementing [MVP](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=mvp+architecture+in+.net&oq=MVP&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l4.1456.1767.0.4181.3.3.0.0.0.1.625.1398.3-2j0j1.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.2.hp.R1JcOI_mgpk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42261806,d.b2I&fp=7d19122e3e84b4fa&biw=1280&bih=962). It may give you a new way to look at solutions for your problems.

You can even create both forms in same project. Process the data in a separate library.

Answer (score 0):

if that is want you want to do - the you could do it like this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile("Server.GUI.LocalGUI.dll");
dynamic o = a.CreateInstance("ServerManager");
o.Method();
```

But i don't recommend this, unless you absolutly have to. Using the `dynamic` keyword can be at shortcut - but sometimes a shortcut to a place you don't want to go..